# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'contact' available as request attribute

Tags: spring, jsp, servlets, spring-mvc

I am trying to create a simple project using spring mvc +maven+ jpa hibernate.

My jsp page is :

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<div>
<form:form action="contact.html" method="post" commandName="contact" >

<div>
<label for="firstname">First Name</label>
<form:input path="firstname"/>
<form:errors path="firstname" cssClass="error"/>
</div>

<div>
<label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
<form:input path="lastname"/>
<form:errors path="lastname" cssClass="error"/>
</div>

<div>
<label for="telephone">Telephone</label>
<form:input path="telephone"/>
<form:errors path="telephone" cssClass="error"/>
</div>

<div>
<label for="email">Email</label>
<form:input path="email"/>
<form:errors path="email" cssClass="error"/>
</div>

<div>
<form:button name="submit" value="submit">Add Contact</form:button>
</div>
```

My contact.html controller :

```
package com.corasent.contacts.controllers;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.corasent.contacts.form.Contact;
import com.corasent.contacts.service.ContactService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("contact.html")
public class ContactManagerController {


@Autowired
ContactService cs;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String contactController()
{
    System.out.println("In controller");
    ModelMap map=new ModelMap();
    Contact contact=new Contact();
    map.addAttribute("contact", contact);
    return "contacts";
}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView getInfo(@ModelAttribute Contact contact, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest req)
{
    ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView("contacts");
    String name=contact.getFirstname();
    System.out.println("name is="+name);
    cs.validate(contact, result);
    if(result.hasErrors())
    {

        return mv ;
    }

    System.out.println("in post method");
    return mv;


}

public ContactService getCs() {
    return cs;
}

public void setCs(ContactService cs) {
    this.cs = cs;
}
```

}

I know that the commandName in jsp is the bean that has to be passed to the controller. the same bean is initiated in controller but seems to be not working. its giving me the above error. i am also pasting the stackTrace.

```
ERROR: org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag - Neither BindingResult nor     plain target object for bean name 'contact' available as request attribute
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'contact' available as request attribute
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:179)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:199)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:165)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:152)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:143)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:127)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:421)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:103)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.jsp.contacts_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(contacts_jsp.java:272)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.jsp.contacts_jsp._jspService(contacts_jsp.java:100)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
12 Apr, 2013 12:36:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/contacts] threw     exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/jsp/contacts.jsp at line    10

7: 
8: <div>
9: <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
10: <form:input path="firstname"/>
11: <form:errors path="firstname" cssClass="error"/>
12: </div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String contactController(Model model)
{
    System.out.println("In controller");
    // ModelMap map=new ModelMap();
    Contact contact=new Contact();
    model.addAttribute("contact", contact);
    return "contacts";
}
```

In your code, you're creating a ModelMap, but it's useless because is being destroyed at the end of the method. Passing the model as a parameter, spring will use it later to fill your JSP.

You have an example [here](https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-mvc-31-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/mvc31/crudcontroller/AccountController.java).

Comment: Thanks @jelies.. but i am getting the same error after adding it as a parameter.

Comment: try changing the name of parameter to `model` (see update). Sometimes spring is very strict with that.

Comment: Yes i did change it to model, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```java
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView contactController()
{
    System.out.println("In controller");
    // First attribute is view name, second model name and last model object
    return new ModelAndView("contacts","contact", new Contact());
}
```

Also, in your form i would change attribute `commandName` by `modelAttribute`, i think i have read that the first one is a kind of deprecated (don't fully trust me here)